# How to average faces between two lines

Tags: faces

Good day, I want to make an accurate landscape for a scene. I am working with a topography map as a background image. I made a detailed grid. I started marking topology lines with shaders. When I raise the shaded portion(s), instead of a smooth linear climb or descent from one topology mark to the next, I get big valleys and mountains because the intermediate faces do not move. I have tried playing with proportional editing, but the inconsistent distance between topography lines is making havoc effecting too much or too little across different areas. The smoothing modifier has similar issues and covers too small a space.

Is there a way to get the faces between two shaded areas to average and smooth out?

EDIT:  I added a few screenshots. My topography map, the flat grid with a few elevation lines, and one sample with raising the elevation lines - - the transition should be smooth, not two hills with a valley. Blender files are located at [This Page](https://www.thinkcreation.org/blender-forum/).

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe show some screenshots how you did that? or even better provide your blend file so we can check it out, thx

Comment: If you had grayscale topographical map, you could simply use it as displacement and get a result as accurate as it can be with that particular map without spending much time and effort.

Comment: Thank you Martynas. Going with a grayscale map might be a way to go ... but as I am new with Blender, how do you accurately scale the heights on grayscale? I want this to be an accurate scale model.

Comment: I fail to see the logic here: it seems you want to do it the way it is not done in and would be a lot more complex if at all possible because you are new to this. You should do things the way they are done and preferably are the easiest to accomplish. If you need it accurate you should get an accurate high resolution, high bit depth, greyscale height map for displacement and match it to real height values.

Comment: I think many years ago I have seen a tutorial about this were they talked about buying satellite elevation data. So I assume it's possible to buy height maps of some specific place made with satellites. It was more than a decade ago, so maybe it's possible to find something free now - I have no idea how that works, but grayscale map is the way to go here. What you show in pictures looks like a real nightmare - I think you would have to model the layers according the lines, remesh and smooth the mesh. Doesn't sound accurate, doesn't sound like a rational task.